# variable inside a variable in a php class

Tags: php

is it possible to copy a variable like this this?

```
class Colours {
   var $var = "one";
   var $var2 = array('something', $var);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated side note: PHP 4 is pretty old; you should be using the PHP 5 OOP syntax unless you're maintaining legacy code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The preferable way is to do this in the constructor of the `Colours` class.  I'm not sure in PHP, but in other languages the order of initialisation of the variables should not be relied upon.

```
class Colours 
{ 
    private $var;
    private $var2;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->var = "one";
        $this->var2 = array('something', $this->var);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to use `$this->var` to access the variable

```
class Colours {
   var $var = "one";
   var $var2 = array('something', $this->var);
}
```

Comment: This won't work because at the time of class declaration, there is no `$this` present yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
     $var = "one";
     $var2 = array('something', $var);
    print_r($var2)
    ?>


 I got the following output 



     Array 
    (
            [0] => something
            [1] => one
    )
```

Comment: He means in a class. In which it would be $this->var.